# How to customize grails field plugin

Tags: grails

How can I customize the template of my field plugin? how to apply bootstrap classes to it?
Where can I get the default template of a f:field (for example) to customize it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check documentation of grails field plugin, I think is very clear [Grails Field Plugin Custimization Page](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/guide/index.html#customizingFieldRendering)

In resume, you have to create gsp file templates, for the diferent fields, it can be done by varios options for example property type, propery name, controller, action, etc. In those template files you can apply the bootstrap clases you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, I've already read that but it's not clear (for me), they're not explaining how to create a template, for example if I want to modify the f:field and apply a different in class in function of the type of the field (a class if it's simple text input, another if it's a file input ...

Comment: I edited my answer with an example, I hope it helps you

Comment: I think @saywow (and myself) was expecting some sort of a default template to start with, and just change some details where needed. But the plugin generate each field from code, and not from a gsp template that could by easily changed.

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2016/01/what-the-f-is-ftable/

It explains how  to customise templates in its final part.
It gives, for instance, the default template for <f:table>, which is located in https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/blob/master/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp

I'm still giving it a try but that was really hard to find. Docs are not very clear on this matter. Hope it helps!