# How to change what the Edit and Delete links point to in the show view in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails3

How does one modify what the Edit and Delete links point to in the `show` view? Been trying to find it for a long time but can't figure it out and I'd like to be able to somehow have them take the params into account so that instead of `/edit` they would point to, say, `/edit?frequency=0&unit=Q&lang=EN` (I'm using a composite-id table so that's what my links look like).

I mean something like `_table.gsp` for links in the list/index view, where you can do for example:

```
<td><g:link action="show" params="${bean.getPK()}"><f:display bean="${bean}" property="${p.property}" displayStyle="${displayStyle?:'table'}" theme="${theme}"/></g:link></td>
```

, but for links in the show view.

Comment: How are you creating those links now?

Comment: @doelleri - I'm not, the views are scaffolded, not my doing

Comment: Tried generating them and looking inside the files but I don't see a place to do that there so I reckon it must be someplace else.

Comment: f:display isn't this where the magic happens the g:link show is generic grails link method. https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/formfields/FormFieldsTagLib.groovy#L319 is where this magic happens - you could download run locally - put in printlns debug to work out what f:display is doing .. Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986542/how-to-customize-grails-field-plugin